# Вызов хост функции из lua, которая получает параметры из с++ объекта

Tags: c++, lua

У меня есть в с++ коде объект, например

> TestObj Test();

Мне хочется в функцию, которая будет вызываться из Lua скрипта, передать не только Луа стек, но и ссылку на этот объект.
Т.е. вместо:

```
int lua_getOneString(lua_State *L)
{  
  lua_pushstring(L, "Hello");  
  return 1;  //Количество возвращаемых аргументов
}
```

я хочу сделать что то наподобии такого (это нужно, чтобы не делать объект **TestObj**  глобальным):

```
int lua_getOneString(lua_State *L, TestObj & obj)
    {  
      lua_pushstring(L, obj.pushStringToLua());  
      return 1;  //Количество возвращаемых аргументов
    }
```

Не могу найти информацию по этому поводу, а если сделать так, то компилятор ругается:

> note:   initializing argument 2 of 'void lua_pushcclosure(lua_State*,
>   lua_CFunction, int)'  LUA_API void  (lua_pushcclosure) (lua_State *L,
>   lua_CFunction fn, int n);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

все функции вызываемые из `lua` должны иметь одну и ту же сигнатуру: `int (lua_State *)` - так что и вашу функцию нужно привести к этому виду. Есть два варианта: сделать ваш `TestObj` статическим (что хороший вариант для фабрики например), либо получать его из `lua` стэка как параметр. Подозреваю, что вас интересует второй вариант (во всяком случае первый вариант тривиален).

Для того, чтобы получить ваш `TestObj` из `lua` стэка вам сначала нужно его туда запихнуть - но как это сделать? В `lua` есть специальный тип `userdata`, с помощью которого можно представлять объекты из `c`-кода. Он может представлять из себя простой указатель или некоторый объем памяти выделенный прямо на стэке `lua`. Во втором случае интерпретатор сам освободит занимаемую память, что весьма хорошо, если ваш объект состоит из базовых типов, вроде `int`, `float`, `c`-массивы фиксированного размера и т.д. для которых не требуется вызывать деструктор. Если же деструктор должен быть вызван (например когда вы используете `new` или используете контейнеры, выделяющие память в куче), то придется написать еще и финализатор.

Продемонстрируем немного кода:

```c
/**\brief push new TestObj to lua stack
 */
int lua_new_obj(lua_State *state) {
  void *addr = lua_newuserdata(state, sizeof(TestObj));
  TestObj *obj = new (addr) TestObj{};

  // XXX also you can use light userdata
  // TestObj *obj = new TestObj{};
  // lua_pushlightuserdata(state, obj);

  return 1;
}

/**\brief get TestObj from lua stack and do something
 */
int lua_foo(lua_State *state) {
  void *addr = lua_touserdata(state, 1);
  TestObj *obj = reinterpret_cast<TestObj *>(addr);
  obj->doSomething();
  return 0;
}

/**\brief call desctructor TestObj
 * \note needed only if you use lightuserdata, or if fou your TestObj destructor must be called
 */
int lua_finilize(lua_State *state) {
  void *addr = lua_touserdata(state, 1);
  TestObj *obj = reinterpret_cast<TestObj *>(addr);
  obj->~TestObj();
  return 0;

  // XXX if you use lightuserdata then you need free memory
  // delete obj; // destructor calls automaticly
}
```

Этот код не совершенен, так как есть две очевидные проблемы: необходимо вручную вызывать финализатор (в случае `lightuserdata` или если требуется вызов деструктора у объекта) и проверка входных прараметров (если передать любую другую `usedata` в вашу функцию, то в лучшем случае ваша прога сразу упадет, в худшем - не упадет). Но и у этих проблем есть решение - метатаблицы! Да, для `userdata` как и для таблиц можно устанавливать свои метатаблицы, но это уже другая история

Comment: Благодарю. Мне еще учиться и учиться...